# Move least frequent S3 buckets to glacier automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Is there anyway to move less frequent **S3** buckets to **glacier** automatically? I mean to say, some option or service searches on **S3** with least access date and then assign **lifecycle policy** to them, so they can be moved to **glacier**? or I have to write a program to do this? If this not possible, is there anyway to assign **lifecycle policy** to all the buckets at once? 
Looking for some feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No this isn't possible as a ready made feature.  However, there is something that might help, [Amazon S3 Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/analytics-storage-class.html)

This produces a report of which items in your buckets are less frequently used.  This information can be used find items that should be archived.

It could be possible to use the S3 Analytics output as input for a script to tag items for archiving.  However, this complete feature (find infrequently used items and then archive them) doesn't seem to be available as a standard product

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will look into the analytics. I want to ask, what kind of script you refer here? some python script? or something like cloudformation?

Comment: the sort of script I mean is something that can run the AWS API via an SDK, read the data from the S3 Analytics and then alter the items in the S3 bucket.  Personally I would use Python boto but there are SDK for java, .Net, Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, Go and C++.  See https://aws.amazon.com/tools/  Pick the language you are happiest with.

Comment: ah got it now. I will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a tag or prefix to your buckets.

Create lifecycle rule to target that tag or prefix to group your buckets together and assign/apply a single lifecycle policy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Comment: From the link you refer, In point 4 it says: "To apply this lifecycle rule to all objects with a specified name prefix (that is, objects with names that begin with a common string), type in a prefix. You can also limit the lifecycle rule scope to one or more object tags. You can combine a prefix and tags." So to my understanding, this tagging or prefix is for objects inside the bucket, not for the buckets itself.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlifecycle.html   there isn't a life cycle rule for doing things to "less frequently used" items automatically.  There are expiry times, current versions and that's all.  Maybe there should be, but at the moment that's the way it goes!